# Can Excel copy and paste formulas and automatically adjust by more than one cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have one column with values in every nth cell that I also want to have one after another in another column. Individually referencing every nth cell is impractical, so I'd like to copy and paste one reference formula in the column. Is there a way to do this without using VBA?

Answer (score 0):

If your first data cell is A1, first formula is in B1, and N=5, then sample formula would be:

```
=OFFSET($A$1,5*ROW(B1)-1,0)
```